# Downloading image file with react native fetch blob

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn react native and how to download files to the device. I know you can do this with react native file system but that does not support authentication which I need. React native fetch blob does support this.

For education purposes, I want to have the code from the first answer to this question recreated in react native fetch blob instead of react native file system.

I someone could write sutch an examlple form me I would be super tankfull.

Question: [Downloading data files with React Native for offline use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815583/downloading-data-files-with-react-native-for-offline-use)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's work fine on Android:

```
export const download = (url, name) => {
  const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
  let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir;
  let options = {
    fileCache: true,
    addAndroidDownloads: {
      useDownloadManager: true,
      notification: true,
      path: PictureDir + name,
      description: t('downloading_file')
    }
  };
  config(options)
    .fetch('GET', url)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data) {
        alert(t('download_success'));
      } else {
        alert(t('download_failed'));
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Of course, this code just for android. For ios here: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

Answer (score 1):

```
downloadImage(){
   var date      = new Date();
   var url       = "http://debasish.com/image.jpg";
   var ext       = this.getExtention(url);
   ext = "."+ext[0];
   const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob ; 
   let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir
   let options = {
   fileCache: true,
    addAndroidDownloads : {
      useDownloadManager : true,
      notification : true,
      path:  PictureDir + "/image_"+Math.floor(date.getTime() 
          + date.getSeconds() / 2)+ext,
     description : 'Image'
      }
   }
    config(options).fetch('GET', url).then((res) => {
      Alert.alert("Download Success !");
   });
}
  getExtention(filename){
    return (/[.]/.exec(filename)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : 
undefined;
```

}

Comment: downloading image file with rn-fetch-blob. It works fine with Android(React Native). In expo it will not work as Expo doesn't support rn-fetch-blob as of now.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include information/explanation there (not in comments), and also make sure your code is indented properly. The final brace is not code formatted (code needs 4 spaces).