# Download txt file from text in React Native

Tags: react-native, text-files, react-native-fs

I'm trying to Download txt file from a text but that function is not working fine.

**Txt Function**

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

  const txtDownload = () => {
    let path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${filename}.txt`;
    RNFS.writeFile(path, `Here is text`, 'utf8').then((res) => {
      Toast('File saved successfully');
    }
    ).catch((err) => {
      Toast(err);
    });
  }
```

It returns File saved successfully but I can't find file

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/40816573/1283345

Comment: It will not work I have just Text not Url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the path and check the location where it's trying to store. For me, it shows the location as below when I try to store in `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/help.txt`

```
/data/user/0/com.sample/files/help.txt
```

I suspect you were checking in the Documents folder. I don't know if you can write to the Documents folder. But it works for the Download folder using `RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath`.